# Set position of object in SVG path

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have an SVG path and I need to position a circle in that path but the position inside that path must depend on a variable I receive using javascript.

I already got the path's length using `var length = myPath.getTotalLength();` but I don't know how to set the object's position inside that path (or using the path lenght) depending on the variable I get.

The path is a closed circuit. It's a race track and I get the car's position as progress in the track.

Comment: myPath.getPointAtLength()

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see that one!

Answer (score -2):

I search same, but only found "animateMotion" tag:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateMotion
I need control % of moving on path, as you..

Found way:

```html
<svg id="svg_1" width="190" height="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <path d="M10 80 Q 52.5 10, 95 80 T 180 80" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="transparent" id="path_1" />
   <circle cx="" cy="" r="10" fill="blue">
    <animateMotion dur="5s" begin="0s" keyPoints="0.5;1;1;0.25" fill="freeze" keyTimes="0;0.7;0.7;1" calcMode="linear">
     <mpath xlink:href="#path_1" />
    </animateMotion>
   </circle>
</svg>
```

Maybe 'begin' and 'dur' said all time duration, and this 'keyPoints="0.5;1;1;0.3"' is all points that circle pass, I think its percentage, this case it start 0.5 = 50% of all way. Maybe if dur="0s" it no move with animateMotion, and can controll with js..